# Azure DevOps pipeline yaml definition: Parameter always includes selectable value even when it is not checked

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I'm facing an issue where a pipeline parameter used to select which stages to run is defined as:

```
---
parameters:
  - name: deploy_stages
    type: object
    default:
      - Deploy_A
      - Deploy_B
      - Deploy_C

stages:
  - stage: First_Stage
    displayName: First
    jobs:
      - template: template1.yml
        parameters:
          b_selected: ${{ contains(join(' ', parameters.deploy_stages), 'Deploy_B') }}
          stages_used: ${{ join(' ', parameters.deploy_stages) }}

  - stage: Deploy_A
    displayName: Deploy A
    jobs:
      - template: deploy-a.yml
    condition: and(contains('${{ join(' ', parameters.deploy_stages) }}', 'Deploy_A'), succeeded())

  - stage: Deploy_B
    displayName: Deploy B
    jobs:
      - template: deploy-b.yml
    condition: and(contains('${{ join(' ', parameters.deploy_stages) }}', 'Deploy_B'), succeeded())

  - stage: Deploy_C
    displayName: Deploy C
    jobs:
      - template: deploy-c.yml
    condition: and(contains('${{ join(' ', parameters.deploy_stages) }}', 'Deploy_C'), succeeded())
```

Before running the pipeline I can select or deselect stages by clicking on `Stages to run` on Advanced Options:

[image: Selecting stages]

This allows me to select which stages will run (see the `condition` on each of the A, B and C stages) I also want to use this to leverage a boolean variable (`b_selected`) in First_Stage to check if Stage B has been selected beforehand (First_Stage runs before all the others but needs to know if the others are selected or not). So if `Deploy_B` is included in the parameter `deploy_stages` it will be true.

Issue is that, no matter if the stage is selected or deselected, above variable `b_selected` will always be true. And thus on the template `template1.yml` used to define First_Stage I want to use the variable in:

```
  - job: DEBUG_Parameter
    displayName: "DEBUG if Deploy_B is selected"
    variables:
      variable1: ${{ parameters.b_selected }}
      variable2: ${{ parameters.stages_used }}
    steps:
      - script: |
          echo $(variable1) variable value
          echo STAGES $(variable2)
          if [[ $(variable1) == "True" ]]; then
            echo Deploy_B selected
          fi
```

Job outputs that the variable is `True` and that the values in `parameters.stages_used` are all the default stages I use to define the parameter on the pipeline (Deploy_A, Deploy_B and Deploy_C) even if I manually deselect one of them.

Trying to troubleshoot: If I change the comparison to something I know won't ever exist on the parameter, it will be `False` (ie if I change the line to `b_selected: ${{ contains(join(' ', parameters.deploy_stages), 'This_is_not_included_so_it_will_fail') }}`

Only way to make it work kinda as expected is to comment out the stage from the parameter default definitions, but its not dynamic. I want to be able to choose the stages before each run by selecting them.

ie: This makes it output false too:

```
---
parameters:
  - name: deploy_stages
    type: object
    default:
      - Deploy_A
      #- Deploy_B
      - Deploy_C

stages:
[...]
```

As this same technique is used on the same pipeline to select certain stages to run or not, so I fail to grasp why its failing to evaluate into a boolean correctly. I don't know why `stages_used` contains all the stages defined and not all the stages selected.

Comment: The way you're approaching this is weird. Why not make *each* stage a separate `bool` parameter?

Comment: additionally if you can match your templates with your stage names I'd recommend a loop over the objects.

Comment: @DanielMann I did not design this setup, but need to maintain it. A total refactor is desirable and probably the most correct option, but its not something I can do now. Still, even if "wierd", I fail to understand why the parameter and boolean variables behave like they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The issue:

I was confusing two different things.

The parameter `deploy_stages` is defined by our pipeline and is different to the internal mechanism used by Azure Devops to mark which stages have been selected to run.

So I was expecting one mechanism (Azure DevOps selector) to alter the results of another, the custom-defined parameter `deploy_stages`.

### How to reference stages selected to run:

During conversations with MS Support there was a reference to a variable (`variables['RELEASE_SELECTED_STAGES']`) that allegedly contained the information of the stages selected by using "Stages to run" on Advanced Options, but it was later denied by them. According to the answers MS gave me, there's currently no way to reference which stages have been selected to run.